# Show that P(y) is a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Suppose that $Q: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial defined by $Q(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x^i$. Let $P : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $Q(\frac{y-a}{b-a}) = P(y)$. Then, $P(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i (\frac{y-a}{b-a})^i $. How can I reduce this to $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i y^i$ for some $d_i$ so that I can show that $P$ is also a polynomial?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you are trying to do. The sum of polynomials is a polynomial and the binomial theorem shows that $y \mapsto ( { y-a \over b-a})^i $ is a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

$P(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i (\frac{y-a}{b-a})^i= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{c_i}{(b-a)^i} (y-a)^i.$ Applying Binomial Theorem to each $(y-a)^i$ term you can see that it is a polynomial in $y.$ You can view it as a polynomial in $Y=y-a,$ just a translation of $y.$